# Copy observations based on the row number in R

Tags: r

My data frame (x) is:

```
c1 c2 

Aa 02 

Bb 03 

Cc 02
```

I'd like to create a column c3 copying the observation in c1 based on the row number in c2:

```
c1 c2 c3 

Aa 02 Bb 

Bb 03 Cc

Cc 02 Bb
```

I'm working with base R and I can't download packages.

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work... I'm getting a copy of the first row of c1.

Comment: Making fewer assumptions, `x$c3 = x$c1[as.numeric(as.character(x$c2))]` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this data:

```
x = read.table(text = 'c1 c2 
Aa 02 
Bb 03 
Cc 02 ', header = T)
```

Here's a solution:

```
x$c3 = x$c1[as.numeric(as.character(x$c2))]
#   c1 c2 c3
# 1 Aa  2 Bb
# 2 Bb  3 Cc
# 3 Cc  2 Bb
```

`as.numeric(as.character())` is a very safe way to convert something to numeric--it will work whether the source is `factor` or `character` (or already `numeric`). Though if you look at the class, `class(x$c2)` you can be more judicious about exactly what conversion is needed.